# Tabula-py - Pdf Extraction

Tags: python, pdf-extraction, tabula-py

while extracting table from pdf using tabula..last 3 rows are not extracting..can anyone let me know where I'm going wrong?

I used read_pdf and give the path,pages=all,multiple_table=True and stream=True as parameters

Comment: Obviously depends on the specific example - which you did not provide. Pease refer the file / page where this happens.